# Custom query: sort custom-post-type archive by title

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor

I'm trying to sort posts by title (instead of date) within a custom post type archive in Elementor. I've set up a custom query and trying to target the custom post type 'glossary' but I'm doing something wrong... can anyone help?

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'glossary_sort_order'); 
        function glossary_sort_order($query){
            if(is_post_type_archive( $post_type, 'glossary', true )):
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            endif;    
        };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**You were close!** `pre_get_posts` is the right action hook, but you've got to check if it's the main query too.
We also want to exclude the admin side (really important) with `! is_admin()`, finally we check if we are on an `archive.php` page and we check the post type using `get_query_var()`.

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `is_admin()` | [Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) |
| `is_archive()` | [Determines whether the query is for an existing archive page.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) |
| `is_main_query(`) | [Determines whether the query is the main query.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query/) |
| `get_query_var()` | [Retrieves the value of a query variable in the WP_Query class.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) |

```
<?php
/**
* do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', WP_Query $this )
*
* @param  $this  WP_Query
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/
*/
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) { // ... the exclamation point "!" is a logical php operators, means NOT, @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
    if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'glossary' ) { // ... we could combine both if statements, I prefer it like that
      // ... stuff to modified on the main query
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'glossary' ) ); // ... here as a redundancy, can be omitted
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 ); // ... speak for itself, -1 to display all associated posts
      $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    };
  };
} ); ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- `WP_Query` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Thank you so much for your corrects and knowledge, that's very helpful.

I'm still having trouble with it though – it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using it with a custom query with Elementor Pro posts widget and I wonder if there's any issue with Elementor... Here is an archive page it relates to: https://progressiveeconomyforum.com/glossary/letter/a/

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer still didn't work for me, although I do appreciate the helpful feedback from @amarinediary

Here is the code that eventually worked for me:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/glossary_archives', function ( $query ) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1000 );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
```

});

Thank you