# Sort Archive Post Widget of Elementor by title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, elementor

I am actually struggling to sort the Archive Posts widget of Elementor by title. Indeed, I use it on taxonomy archives that are taxonomies for my custom post type named "my_custom_post". These are custom taxonomies, created with CPTUI.

How can I sort the posts in the archive posts widget everywhere, I mean on the main archive but also on these taxonomy archives ?

I have seen many different solutions but neither worked for me :

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
    function my_change_sort_order($query){
        if(is_archive() && is_post_type_archive( 'my_custom_post' )):
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        endif;    
    };
```

from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-posts-by-title-in-archive/

and

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
      if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) { 
        if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'my_custom_post' ) {
          $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'my_custom_post' ) );
          $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
          $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
          $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        };
      };
    } );
```

and

```
    add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_post_archives', function ( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    });
```

both from [Custom query: sort custom-post-type archive by title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707677/custom-query-sort-custom-post-type-archive-by-title).

Because neither of this work, I start asking myself about what I am doing wrong ... Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance !